# Serialization value without create object C#

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I have work with a `MainWindow.xaml` class and I want to save some values of my class in my case: `private static int bestrecord = 0;`

How can I save this value and restore it without a created class just for it?

Because with Serialization you can save only an object and I just want to save this variable.

Thank you.

Comment: Try looking into application settings - they can be saved for each user for an application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so... if the conveniently available API uses objects / serialization: create an object with one property on it, for the purposes of serialization? honestly, you're not going to be saving / restoring it very often, so why worry about it?

Comment: What about creating binary file, that stores your value?

Comment: @Baldrick good idea to use application settings. But i have one question: Where is save the data ?

Comment: By default, into a file in your user application data folder. It's configured as part of your profile, and managed by windows through registry keys. The great things is you can load and save these settings without worrying too much about where the data is actually stored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a very good way for save my score in xml file.

I'm based on [Examples of XML Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1).

For do that i have create 2 function:

```
private void SerializeElement()
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlElement));
    XmlElement myElement = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("bestRecord");
    myElement.InnerText = bestRecord.ToString();
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("text.xml");
    ser.Serialize(writer, myElement);
    writer.Close();
}
```

and

```
private static int deserialize()
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlElement));
    StreamReader lecteur = new StreamReader("text.xml");
    XmlDocument myElement = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement p = (XmlElement) ser.Deserialize(lecteur);
    lecteur.Close();
    return int.Parse(p.InnerText);
}
```

the xml file look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bestRecord>8</bestRecord>
```

Comment: Your solution does work, but it is mixing concepts. If you want to write to a file with only one value, I would recommend just write a single number in a text file using the static methods of the `File` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Application Settings functionality, which is pretty much designed for saving simple variables which are part of the application state, and need to be restored in future sessions.

The documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx).

Once you've creating a setting using the designer in the IDE, you can load settings like this:

```
var mySetting = Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName;
```

You can edit your variable normally and save it like this

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName = mySetting ;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```